Cannot import name 'setuptools' from setuptools
When installing a package I get the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'setuptools' from setuptools
I am on the latest setuptools version 69.5.1 at the time of writing.

That package should just import setuptools, that extra recursive import is entirely unnecessary and I have no idea why setuptools had that in the first place.

Yes, I was surprised to see from setuptools import setuptools in the setup.py that was the first domino to fall when I was debugging.

I needed to downgrade setuptools. The package I was trying to install does have from setuptools import setuptools in their setup.py , so the error makes sense.
After some experimentation it looks like this change was introduced in the move from   version 68.x.x to 69.x.x. So versions of setuptools <69 seem to work.
pip install setuptools==69.0.0
python -c "from setuptools import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)" #  ImportError: cannot import name 'setuptools' from setuptools
python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"  # 69.0.0

---

pip install setuptools==68.0.0
python -c "from setuptools import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)" #  68.0.0



Seems to actually be <68.2.
